# Closure obtained from reflection cannot properly address input parameters

Tags: swift, reflection, closures, mirror

A hardcore Swift question I guess. Given this trivial code:

```swift
struct Container {
    let closure: (Int) -> Void
}

let container = Container { param in
    print("\(param)")
}
```

One can assume calling `container.closure(42)` will print out `42`, which is true.

However, if this same closure is retrieved from the `container`'s `Mirror`:

```swift
let mirror = Mirror(reflecting: container)
let closure = mirror.children
    .first(where: { $0.label == "closure" })!
    .value as! ((Int) -> Void)
```

... then calling `closure(42)` distorts the parameter's value, and it prints out `6166589480`.

The same thing happens if you use `String` instead of `Int`, and I assume with other types too. If I pass a reference to an object, expectedly that reference get messed up too and I get `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` when trying to access the object.

Is this a bug in Swift / Xcode 13.2 or am I missing something?

Comment: I think this is a limitation of Mirror, reflection functionality in swift isn't very advanced.